# Arrangement of Numbers to Get a Common Sum

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I'm having trouble with a math problem. I need to arrange 6 numbers on a certain diagram:

[image]

At every intersection of two circles, I have to put one of these six numbers: 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, or 7. The sum of all of the numbers on each circle must be the same. Is it possible to arrange these numbers this way?

Comment: You mean no number that belongs to all three?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Oh, you misunderstood. Each section does not get its own number. The intersections get numbers, and each number is on one of the circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the numbers is $33$.  Each occurs twice, total $66$.  Three circles, four numbers adding up to $22$ on each.  The $7$ must be matched with $6,5,4$.  The $7$ is on the intersection of two circles; each of these circles must include a $4$; but there is only one $4$, so it must be on the other intersection of the same two circles.  The rest is easy, and there are various solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  I misunderstood the question.  Anyway, I'm keeping my answer here in case it provides additional ideas...

[image]

The sum of the numbers in each circle is 17.

Comment: Technically, all of the numbers are in intersections, and the diagram just makes it look like it's "alone."

Comment: This wasn't actually what the question looked like. You need to put each number on the circumference of the circles, where the circles meet.